# SwiftUI How to prevent NavigationLink from popping when I update the source in parent view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I need to update the order of the source in the parent view ForEach loop when an action is triggered in child NavigationLink. But the NavigationLink will pop itself when the order changed
Here is an example:

```
ForEach(myEnvironmentObject.myArray, id: \.id) { item in
    NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(item: item)) { MyLabel() }
} 
struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
         Button(action: { 
              myEnvironmentObject.myArray.sort()
          }) {someLabel()}
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include more of your View please?

Comment: Please include a [mre] -- what you have won't compile and in my tests where I built out what was missing, I didn't not experience the same issue you're having

Comment: I solved it after using method from: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/bindable-swiftui-list-elements/